# Add argument to \section to include a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, sectioning

I'm trying to translate a wordpress-blog to a book. Since every article has a title and a titleimage I am looking for a way to pass a titelimage to a section.

I figured out how to create a nice looking section using the tikz package but now I'm wondering how to pass the corresponding picture automatically and not by hand.

Something like `\section{title}{picture.jpg}` would be great. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Here is what i got so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %Custom Section title
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=1.0cm, top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}


%%Custom Section-Titles
\newcommand*\sectionlabel{}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\gdef\sectionlabel{}
        \normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\color{THDblue}}
        {\gdef\sectionlabel{\thesection\ }}{0pt}
    {%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
                \node[anchor=north west] (titelbild) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}};
                \draw[color=THDblue] ($(titelbild.north east) + (15cm,-0.5cm)$) -- ($(titelbild.north east) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) -- (titelbild.north east) -- (titelbild.north west) -- (titelbild.south west) --(titelbild.south east) --($(titelbild.south east) + (0.5cm,0.5cm)$) -- ($(titelbild.south east) + (15cm,0.5cm)$);
                \node[anchor=north west, text width=9cm] at ($(titelbild.north east) + (0.3cm,-0.8cm)$){\sectionlabel#1};
                \end{tikzpicture}
    }

%-------------------------------------

\definecolor{THDblue}{rgb}{0.1000,0.4000,0.4000}


\begin{document}


\chapter{This is the titel of my first chapter}
\section{This is my first section, btw it is a very long title}

\chapter{This is the titel of my second chapter}


\end{document}
```

Comment: May I suggest using something like `\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}` for your example? We don't have the image you refer to in the code of course, but almost everyone will have `example-image`, as it's part of a package called `mwe` that is included in most LaTeX distributions.

Comment: You could simply define a new command `\newcommand*\mysection[1]{\def\secimage{#1}\section}`. This way, you just say `\mysection{<image>}{<title>}` and you may refer to your image as `\secimage`.

Comment: I edited the code to work with example-image. Didn't know about this possibility. I'm pretty new in TeX ;-)

@EricDomenjoud: Now I need to define \secimage somewhere aswell, right? I need to do the link between \secimage and the includegraphics where i can set the width of the image.

Comment: I don't really get it. Can I really use this new `\secimage` command inside the `\titleformat{\section}` block? If so, how? 

I need to have access to the picture, while the sectiontitle is being written by tikz.

I'm sorry, I bet this is all basic stuff for you guys but I'm really having a hard time.

Comment: @Flo - where it says `\includegraphics[...]{example-image}` in your code, write `\includegraphics[...]{\secimage}` instead.

Comment: @Flo. Yes, after `\mysection{<image>}{<title>}`, `\secimage` is defined as the name of your image and you may say `\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{\secimage}` in the `\titleformat{\section}` block. The command `\mysection{<image>}` actually first defines `\secimage` and then calls the normal `\section` command. This means that you can also use `\mysection{<image>}[<short title>]{<title>}` or `\mysection{<image>}*{<title>}`.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the syntax `\section{<title>}{<image>}`, then you can redefine `\section` to capture two mandatory arguments using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %Custom Section title
\usepackage{hyperref,xparse}

%%Custom Section-Titles
\newcommand*\sectionlabel{}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\gdef\sectionlabel{}
    \normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\color{THDblue}}
    {\gdef\sectionlabel{\thesection\ }}{0pt}
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west] (titelbild) at (0,0) {\secimg};
    \draw[color=THDblue] ($(titelbild.north east) + (15cm,-0.5cm)$) -- ($(titelbild.north east) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) -- (titelbild.north east) -- (titelbild.north west) -- (titelbild.south west) --(titelbild.south east) --($(titelbild.south east) + (0.5cm,0.5cm)$) -- ($(titelbild.south east) + (15cm,0.5cm)$);
    \node[anchor=north west, text width=9cm] at ($(titelbild.north east) + (0.3cm,-0.8cm)$){\sectionlabel#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m m}{%
  \def\secimg{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{#4}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \section*
      \oldsection*{#3}%
    }{% \section
      \IfValueTF{#2}
        {% \section[.]{..}
          \oldsection[#2]{#3}
        }{% \section{..}
          \oldsection{#3}
        }%
    }%
}

%-------------------------------------

\definecolor{THDblue}{rgb}{0.1000,0.4000,0.4000}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is the title of my first chapter}
\section{This is my first section, btw it is a very long title}{example-image-a}

\section{This is my second section, btw it is a very long title}{example-image-b}

\section{This is my final section, btw it is a very long title}{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

It is assumed the each `\section` will be accompanied by a picture (hence the fact that the two arguments for `\section` is considered *mandatory*).